# How do I enforece a function return type to be non-primitive or Promise non-primitive?

Tags: typescript, generics, promise, constraints

I'm trying to create a typed function that is only allowed to return non-primitive results. Either sync or async. However, it seems that the `Promise<object>` constraint isn't enforced in the code, since `Promise` itself is already a non-primitive.

```
function nonPrimitiveResult(): object | Promise<object> {
    return {};                  // OK
    return 1;                   // Error
    return undefined;           // Error
    return Promise.resolve({}); // OK
    return Promise.resolve(1);  // OK, why?
    return Promise.resolve();   // OK, why?
}
```

Comment: Promise.resolve(1) return a Promise<number> which is an object same for Promise.resolve() return Promise<void> which is an object

Answer (score 0):

While likely far from a perfect solution, you can model the type of behavior you're after with a conditional type.  The order of the conditional type here is significant, because we're throwing away `Promise<Primitive>` before checking for other types of Promises.

You could arbitrarily make this example stricter by adding more branches to the conditional type to cover the scenarios you don't want.

Unfortunately for it to work, the return statement needs to attempt the cast to the generic type:

```
type Primitive = number | string | boolean;

type X<T> = T extends Primitive ?
  never
  : T extends Promise<Primitive> ?
  never
  : T extends Promise<any> ?
  Promise<T>
  : T;

const nonPrimitiveResult = <T>(): X<T> => {
  return 1 as X<T>; // error
  return true as X<T>; // error
  return "hello world" as X<T>; // error

  return Promise.resolve(1) as X<T>; // error
  return Promise.resolve(true) as X<T>; // error
  return Promise.resolve("hello world") as X<T>; // error

  return Promise.resolve() as X<T>; // error

  return {} as X<T>; // ok
  return Promise.resolve({}) as X<T>; // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to say "Either an `object` that is not a `Promise` at all, or a `Promise<object>`".  Unfortunately the concept "an `object` that is not a `Promise`" is easiest to express as a [subtraction type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183), which is not currently supported in TypeScript.

One way to proceed instead is to describe an object type that is definitely not a `Promise`, and includes *most* non-primitives you might want to allow, without allowing all of them.  For example, it might be reasonable to expect that, if the return value of `nonPrimitiveResult()` contains a property named `then`, that result is a `Promise`.  Or equivalently, if the result is *not* a `Promise`, then it does *not* contain a property named `then`.  If that's a reasonable compromise, you can change `object | Promise<object>` to `{then?: never} | Promise<object>`.  The type `{then?: never}` means "this is an object without a defined `then` property".

In that case your signature becomes:

```
function nonPrimitiveResult(): { then?: never } | Promise<object> {
  return {};                  // OK
  return 1;                   // Error
  return undefined;           // Error
  return Promise.resolve({}); // OK
  return Promise.resolve(1);  // Error
  return Promise.resolve();   // Error      
}
```

and all of your cases behave as you'd like.  This is a workaround, of course.  If the statement "a result with a `then` property must be a `Promise`" does not apply in practice, then you will end up prohibiting valid objects:

```
function nonPrimitiveResult(): { then?: never } | Promise<object> {
  return {then: "theDinosaursCame"};  // Error, uh oh
}
```

So it's not a perfect solution.  You can be more clever and start describing a union of types that more closely represents "an object that is not a `Promise`", for example:

```
type NotAFunction = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | { call?: NotAFunction };
declare function nonPrimitiveResult(): { then?: NotAFunction } | Promise<object>;
```

but that starts getting more and more complex with less and less marginal benefit.  So I'd probably just stick with `{then?: never}` unless I ran into a use case that made it unworkable.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, non-primitives in JS (and therefore TypeScript) include `object` (and `array` which is still an object behind the scenes).

So the most literal way to answer your question is:

```
async function nonPrimitiveResult(): Promise<object> {
   // ... implementation
}
```

As an explanation of that answer, lets delve into why you were getting strange results in your IDE.

**Explaining why you were seeing what you were seeing**

The reason why you're getting a strange false-positive is due to the fact that you're not marking the function as `async`. If you were to do that then things would become much more clear.

```
async function nonPrimitiveResult(): Promise<object> {
    return Promise.resolve(1); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'object'.
}
```

**More context:**

1) Why you should always mark every function that returns a promise as async

- In your original example, the transpiled (i.e. resulting javascript code) would not have been wrapped in a generator. Which means that nonPrimitiveResult would have returned a Promise object which is in-fact an object-- it's just an object that has a `then` function on it. So I would recommend utilizing `tslint` to help enforce you to always await a function that returns a promise. In particular, the `promise-function-async` rule is what you need: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/promise-function-async/

2) On returning an object or a Promise

- Once you mark the function as `async` you'll find that you can no longer represent the response type as `object | Promise<object>` because you'll get this error:

  - `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.`
- *Why?* Because the result of any async function is a Promise of a someday result.